# Add current date or time in the converted file using Pandas script

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to convert .csv to .xlsx using Pandas script. I want the filename to be appended or suffixed with current date(i.e. The converted xlsx file should display like this - sourcefile_12152022.xlsx)

I tried this using - import time - but this is not working for me.

```
import time

TodaysDate = time.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
sourcefile= TodaysDate +".xlsx"

DataSet.to_excel(sourcefile, sheet_name='sheet1', index=False)
```

This is the original script that I tried before trying to add using  - import time

```
import os
os.chdir("/opt/alb_test/alb/albt1/Source/alb/al/conversion/scr")

# Reading the csv file

import pandas as pd
print(pd.__file__)
df_new  = pd.read_csv("sourcefile.csv", sep="|", header=None).dropna(axis=1, how="all")

# saving xlsx file

df_new.to_excel("sourcefile.xlsx", index=False)
```

Kindly guide me on this conversion.

Answer (score 3):

Use `f-string`s for generate actual datetime use [`Timestamp`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.html):

```
file = f"sourcefile_{pd.Timestamp('now').strftime('%d-%m-%Y')}.xlsx"
df_new.to_excel(file, index=False)
```